# Why am I getting this error in C?

Tags: c

I have been getting a strange error when I use gcc to compile my c code.

This is my error: http://pastebin.com/dN4xXbQZ

This is my code:

```
// MemroyAllocationTester.c
// 2.20.11

// calloc() function allocates a group of objects.
// rather than malloc() which allocates a group of bytes.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for calloc and free

main()
{
    unsigned num;
    int *pointer;

    printf("Enter the number of type int to allocate: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    pointer = (int*)calloc(num, sizeof(int));

    //if (pointer == NULL)
    //  puts("Memory allocation failed.");
    //else
    //  puts("Memory allocation was successful.");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: No problem for me under ubuntu. BTW, (int*) cast is useless

Comment: What compiler are you using? Could it be that you have converted the source file to Unicdoe by accident and you get the compile warnings because the compiler things it was an ASCII input file?

Comment: I use terminal to compile my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your source file is Unicode (UTF-16), but your compiler is expecting ASCII (or UTF-8). You need to save your source file as ASCII (or UTF-8).

You *could* try compiling with `gcc -finput-charset=UTF-16` but I suspect that won't work because then it might try to interpret the header files as UTF-16 also, which they aren't.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works now. I think i typed this file on a Windows machine and i might have saved it in the wrong format.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has a [unicode byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`0xFEFF`) at the start of the file.  I expect you don't want that.  Get rid of it and compile boring old fashioned plaintext.  Likely your file is UTF-16 for some reason.  It looks like your compiler can't handle that - change it to UTF-8 or ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this has to do with `calloc`, you probably managed to have some non-ascii characters in your sourcefile.

The only thing that I see you shouldn't do in C is to cast the return from `calloc` or `malloc`.